# GCP machine images and credentials

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a question regarding Google Cloud custom images and how/if credentials are stored.  Namely, if I customize a VM and save the machine image with public access, am I possibly exposing credentials??

In particular, I'm working on a cloud-based application that relies on a "custom" image which has both gsutil and docker installed.  Basic GCE VMs have gsutil pre-installed but do **not** have docker.  On the other hand, the container-optimized OS have docker, but do **not** have gsutil.  Hence, I'm just starting from a basic debian image and installing docker to get what I need.

Ideally, when I distribute my application, I would like to just expose that customized image for public use; this way, users will not have to spend extra effort to make their own images.

My concern, however, is that since I have used gsutil on the customized VM, persisting this disk to an image will inadvertently save some credentials related to my project (if so, where are they??).  Hence, anyone using my image will also get those credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your situation. I created a [customer image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images#creating_a_custom_image) from the disk of an instance who could access my project Storage buckets. Then, I [shared](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/sharing-images-across-projects#share) the image for another user in a different project. The user could [create](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/sharing-images-across-projects#accessing_images) an instance out of that shared image. However, when he tried to [access](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects) my project buckets, he encountered AccessDeniedException error.

According to this reproduction and my investigations, your credentials are not exposed with the image. [IAM grant permissions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles) are based on roles given to a user, a group, or a service account. Sharing images can't grant them to others.

Furthermore, (as Patrick W mentioned below) any thing you run from within a GCE VM instance will use the VM's service account (unless otherwise specified). As long as the service account has access to the bucket, so will your applications (including docker containers.

Comment: That's great to know-- thanks!  It's good to have someone else recreate it, although it remains a proof by example.  I am often still confused/surprised at situations where certain permissions work or not, depending on the various hidden files, etc. that are on the VM.

Comment: If you explain more about the details of the situation where certain permissions work or not (hidden files, etc), I will be happy to assist further. p.s. please make sure not to post private or critical details of your project here.

Comment: One instance where I'm surprised is when I create a docker container on GCP.  In that container (below), I'm able to access my buckets without  providing credentials.  How does it know?
```FROM debian:stretch
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    python3-dev \
    python3-pip
RUN pip3 install google-cloud-storage
ADD list_buckets.py /opt/
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/list_buckets.py"]```

script:
```#! /usr/bin/python3
from google.cloud import storage
storage_client = storage.Client()
buckets = list(storage_client.list_buckets())
print(buckets)```

Comment: any thing you run from within a GCE VM instance will use the VM's service account (unless otherwise specified). As long as the service account has access to the bucket, so will your applications (including docker containers)